# Rest APIのサーバ-クライアント間通信でstring文字列の受け渡し

Tags: java, spring

Rest APIのサーバ-クライアント間通信でクエリパラメタでなく、別の方法でString型の文字列を受け渡したいです。試したソースはそれぞれ以下の通りです。

クライアント側

```
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PLAIN_TEXT);

String sendparam = "test";

HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String,>(sendparm, headers);

restTemplate.postForObject( url, request , String.class);
```

サーバ側

```
@RequestMapping(value="/test",consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_PLAIN_TEXT,METHOD="POST")

 public void testPost(@ResponseBody HttpEntity<String> request) {
 String receiveParam = request.getBody;
 }
```

サーバ側のreceiveparamにsendparamの内容を受け渡したいですが、上手く動作しませんでした。
ご指摘や参考になるURLなどご教示いただけたら幸いです。

Comment: どううまく動作しなかったのかわからないのですが、`request.getBody();` と括弧は必要ないですか？

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/159833

Answer (score 1):

@RequestBodyはBodyのタイプを宣言するAnnotationです。
つまりHttpEntityの宣言はいらないです、直接Stringを宣言してください。

```
@PostMapping(value = "/api/v1/snippet")
public ResponseEntity<?> create(@RequestBody String text) {
    System.out.println(String.format("Received text is %s.", text));
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

マレーシア人ですから、日本語下手でごめんね。